# How to do async api requests in a GAE application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I am working on an application which is based on GAE with python 2.7.13. What I want to do is that to make a bunch of async API calls inside a handler. Something like that:

```
class MakeRequests(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def post(self, *v, **kv):
       *do an async api call#1*
       *do an async api call#2*
       *do an async api call#3*

       *wait for response from all of above api requests*
       *make response in a way like if call#1 failes, make it's expected*
       *attributes in response as None, if call#2 succeeds add it's*
       *attributes in response etc. This is just an example.*
```

For that purpose, I have tried libraries like `asyncio`, `grequests`, `requests` and `simple-requests`, they don't seems to be working because either they are not compatible with with `GAE` or with `python 2.7.13`.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urlfetch, which is bundled by default with GAE [has a way of making asynchronous calls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests?csw=1#issuing_an_asynchronous_request):

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

def post(self, *v, **kv):
  rpcs = []
  for url in urls:
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
    rpcs.append(rpc)

  results = [rpc.get_result() for rpc in rpcs]
  # do stuff with results
```

If, for some reason you don't want to use urlfetch you can parallelize the requests manually by using [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) and a [synchronized Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to read the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped!