# API gateway for appengine micro-services?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

Im moving a monolithic App "Rest Mobile Backend" written in Java into a micro-services App
This App is currently hosted in AppEngine in GCP as a single service and hence will be broken down into 8-10 services in App Engine.

Now Im still in the design phase, and my concern is simply that for some client's calls I need to call multi services sequentially or in parallel, how to provide such thing?

I've heard about API Gateway term but Im not sure if GCP have such thing ready to use?

I have heard about NginX but it needs to be installed in a VM and hence handling its scaling up/down and security by myself and I dont want that since my team is pretty small. I need to leverage the Power of scaling up/down of the App Engine in all my system so  my team just need to write code and upload it and nothing more to work about.

Comment: Is your question how to make API calls in parallel?  If so, that is a completely separate issue than splitting your app into multiple services.  You'd want to make your API calls asynchronously and then wait for them all to return.

Comment: Yes my question is how to make API calls in Parallel

Comment: With some logic

Comment: When  you talk about API Gateway, do you talk about the AWS product? Or the concept of API Gateway?

Comment: I prefer to have something in GCP since im using the app engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do async api requests in a GAE application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719006/how-to-do-async-api-requests-in-a-gae-application)

Comment: somehow yes, but my question is more into where to deploy this handler in GCP ? since this handler will handle all users  request so it should be scaling up  properly, should I  deploy it in an GAE service? I mean whats the best practice ?

Comment: Something like this ? [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs)

Comment: but this doesnt provide doing requests in parallel

Comment: also it cant take decision based on some requests results

Comment: You could use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run#section-7)

Answer (score 0):

There is this new [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) product in GCP (released September 2020).

It's described as:

> Fully managed gateway for serverless workloads

This seem to match your requirements.

The product is currently in beta, and it has some limitations (it does not currently support [OpenAPI v3](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/openapi-overview)).

The requirements specified in the comments (which you might want to add to your question) are not fulfilled by the GCP's API Gateway, since that gateway is only for securing and monitoring the API itself.

You'll have to develop some logic behind it. As suggested in some comments, a good idea would be:

[GCP API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) -> [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) service to fan out requests in parallel -> All microservices